# While downloading azure blobs to local file system an exception occurs

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

While downloading azure blobs to local file system, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Client-Request-ID=99bdb0e4-2d1c-11e8-8fe6-00155dbf7128 Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Wed, 21 Mar 2018 15:29:09 GMT, Server-Request-ID=1e7ab8f5-101e-0076-5329-c16a24000000, HTTP status code=404, Exception=The specified blob does not exist.
ErrorCode: BlobNotFound<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:1e7ab8f5-101e-0076-5329-c16a24000000Time:2018-03-21T15:29:09.6565984Z</Message></Error>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Commvault\ContentStore\Automation\CloudApps\CloudAppsUtils\cahelper.py", line 483, in download_contents_azure
    session.get_blob_to_path(container_name,fl,fl)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 1817, in get_blob_to_path
    timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 2003, in get_blob_to_stream
    raise ex
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 1971, in get_blob_to_stream
    _context=operation_context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 1695, in _get_blob
    operation_context=_context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\common\storageclient.py", line 354, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\common\storageclient.py", line 289, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\common\storageclient.py", line 275, in _perform_request
    HTTPError(response.status, response.message, response.headers, response.body))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\common\_error.py", line 111, in _http_error_handler
    raise AzureHttpError(message, http_error.status)
azure.common.AzureMissingResourceHttpError: The specified blob does not exist.ErrorCode: BlobNotFound
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>BlobNotFound</Code><Message>The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:1e7ab8f5-101e-0076-5329-c16a24000000
Time:2018-03-21T15:29:09.6565984Z</Message></Error>
```

I'm using the following code to download blobs:

```
def download_contents_azure(self, account_name, account_key, content):
    session=self.create_session_azure(account_name,account_key)
    os.mkdir('in place')
    os.chdir('in place')

    for item in content:
        # s = os.path.basename(item)

        path_to_file = ("/".join(item.strip("/").split('/')[1:]))
        container_name = Path(item).parts[1]
        gen = session.list_blobs(container_name)
        li = []

        for i in gen:
            li.append(i.name)

        if path_to_file in li:
            fl = os.path.basename(path_to_file)

            print(fl)
            c = self.splitall(item)

            for i in range(1,len(c)-1):
                if path.exists(c[i]) is False:
                    os.mkdir(c[i])
                os.chdir(c[i])

            session.get_blob_to_path(container_name,fl,fl)

            for i in range(1,len(c)-1):
                os.chdir("..")
        else:
            c = self.splitall(item)
            for i in range(1,len(c)):
                os.mkdir(c[i])
                os.chdir(c[i])

            generator = session.list_blobs(container_name,path_to_file+'/',delimiter='/')

            for blob in generator:
                bl = os.path.basename(blob.name)
                session.get_blob_to_path(container_name,bl,bl)
```

I've a path in azure (`/container/folder/subfolder`).
I'm trying to download the structure and all the files under `subfolder`. the first file under the `subfolder` gets downloaded and then I've the above exception. Due to this, I'm unable to loop through and print the next items.

Thoughts?

Comment: There's no need to have a new line for ***every*** line of code you have. It makes the post excessively long and difficult to read and follow.

Comment: what does `fl` look like? Also install fiddler and look at the request and paste it here so we can help you why the request is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your line
`session.get_blob_to_path(container_name,fl,fl)`

You have `fl` for `blob_name`.

documentation [here](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/_modules/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.html?highlight=get_blob_to_path) indicates second argument is blob_name while third is file path on file system where to download.

I think your blob name is wrong. Hence it does not exist.

NOTE: consider installing [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) so you can look at the network traces. It allows you to see the raw request.

Comment: Saher, i think there's no issue with the blob name. It gets downloaded and then this exception occurs. And with fiddler i'm seeing many certificate errors.

Comment: Locate the GetBlob call in fiddler the actual one your code makes, is the http result 200 success?

Comment: I got rid of this after doing some exception handling.

Comment: @Sruthi that doesn't make sense. You shouldn't be getting an exception at first place if blob exists.