# Deleting Azure Blobs not deleting parent folders

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

To begin with - I do know that Azure Blob Storage is flat and does not follow a folder structure.

But it still has the ability to mimic the folder structure view if the individual blobs(in my case pdfs) are uploaded using the naming convention of a folder structure path like Main_Folder/Sub_Folder/Test.pdf (found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049629/how-to-create-folder-structure-inside-azure-storage-container-using-powershell))..

I was able to replicate ^ and have uploaded 3 pdfs which are individual pages from a book(#3,#4,#5). Becuase I specified the 'folder structure' in the name of the blobs, it also created #1 and #2 blobs which have `'metadata': {'hdi_isfolder': 'true'}` in the blob metadata.

| # | Blob Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Uppermost_Folder/Book_C' |
| 2 | Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num' |
| 3 | Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num/1.pdf' |
| 4 | Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num/2.pdf' |
| 5 | Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num/3.pdf' |

Now I want to delete everything from #1 to #5.. If I try deleting #1 or #2, I get the below error

```
HttpResponseError: The requested operation is not supported on a directory.
RequestId:abcd
Time:2023-08-01T18
ErrorCode:OperationNotSupportedOnDirectory
Content: OperationNotSupportedOnDirectoryThe requested operation is not supported on a directory.
RequestId:abcd
Time:2023-08-01T18
```

I can delete the #3,#4,#5 successfully but that still keeps #1 and #2 in my blob storage and doesn't automatically delete  them. **How should I delete these #1 and #2 'folders' ?**

FYI , the code I use for deletion in as below:

```
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob='Uppermost_Folder/Book_C')
blob_client.delete_blob(delete_snapshots="include")
```

Comment: Is your storage account ADLS Gen2 account?

Comment: Assuming this is a storage account without hierarchical namespace, Are there any other files or subfolders with files within Uppermost_Folder/Book_C ?

Comment: @AnupamChand Nope. There is nothing within   Uppermost_Folder/Book_C except #3,#4,#5 from the table in my question

Comment: @GauravMantri It's a Blob Storage Account and not ADLS Gen2.  My `Account kind`  is StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Comment: @newbie101 Can you check if hierarchical namespace is enabled on your storage account or not? Also is it possible to attach screen shots from your portal showing the empty folders?

Comment: @AnupamChand not sure if hierarchical namespace is an applicable setting to Blob Storage Account.. I am using a blob storage account and not  ADLS Gen2

Answer (score 0):

> HttpResponseError: The requested operation is not supported on a directory.

The above error tells us that you are trying to remove a directory in Azure Blob Storage, which is not supported.

In Azure Blob Storage, directories are virtual items that do not truly exist as physical items. Instead, they are considered based on the blobs' naming structure.

If you delete all files in the folder it will automatically delete the folder.

You can use the below code to delete all the blobs in a virtual directory.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "your-connection-string"
container_name = "test"
directory_name = "Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num/"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=directory_name)

for blob in blobs:
    container_client.delete_blob(blob.name)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Suppose, if your storage account is hierarchical namespace is enabled. It is considered a data lake storage gen2 account.

In the gen2 account you can able to delete the folder using [azure-storage-file-datalake](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/) package.

**Portal:**

[image]

In the above snippet, It has only the folder looks like the structure **`Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num/`**

Using the below code you can delete the directory.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

connection_string = "your-datalake gen2 storage connection string"
file_system_name = "test" #your-fileystem-name
directory_name = "Uppermost_Folder/Book_C/page_num"

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system_name)

file_system_client.delete_directory(directory_name)
```

**Output:**
[image]

In the above snippet, you can see the **`page_num`** directory is removed successfully.

**Reference:**

[Use Python to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python?tabs=azure-ad#delete-a-directory)

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Can you tell what value I should keep for file_system_name ? You have it as test but I am unable to figure out why you have it as test and what I should put it as

Comment: Also can you tell me the version you are using? I am using 12.12.0 and it's giving me errors at line `file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system_name). and saying Unsupported api version

Comment: @newbie101 file_system_name(test) like a container. same as the 12.12.0 version I have used. 
https://i.imgur.com/MaB5CZr.png.

Comment: do you mind sending the pip freeze screenscap for all your azure libraries. They appear in alphabetical order so should hopefully be easy to take a snippet of :)

Comment: Here it is https://i.imgur.com/RcHC4Dv.png.